# Is there a Saura-Sampradaya today separate from Smarta-Sampradaya?

Tags: puja, surya, smarta, pancayatana, sampradaya

Does an independent Saura-Sampradaya exist today?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saura_(Hinduism)

Or is the cult and philosophy of Surya, like Ishvara, preserved only inside the Panchayatana Puja?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchayatana_puja

Comment: there was martand sun temple in kashmir, konark sun temple in odisha. they must have been saura sampradaya followers